# Trying to run multiple pg pool query functions in one command using 'make-runnable'

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, pool

Learning how to use Postgres and having difficulty calling multiple asynchronous pool functions in a linear manner.

I want to drop all my tables, create all those tables, and seed all those tables in one command on Powershell. I'm using the npm module 'make-runnable' for this. The functions run in isolation, but typing them in one at a time each time I want to try something new is a pain.

I reviewed how the async syntax works, and I've used it successfully in the past. I looked up how pool works, but I just get a lot of explanations on its syntax.

My three functions are basically this structure, and use the same pool.query() call:

```
const createTables = () => {
    const taskTableText = 
        `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
            acts(
                id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1 (),
                name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
                length INTERVAL NOT NULL,
                percent_complete INT NOT NULL,
                start_stamp TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (id)
            )
        `;


    pool.query(taskTableText)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            pool.end();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            pool.end();
        });

}
```

This works well in Powershell, but when I try and do the three together like

```
const makeFresh = async function() {
    const stepOne = await dropTables();
    const stepTwo = await createTables();
    const stepThree = await seedTables();
}
```

One gets called, (or possibly they all try and fire since they are not running one at a time?) seemingly at random since the command can be different each time in the shell's output:

```
--------make-runnable-output--------
undefined
------------------------------------
connected to db
connected to db
connected to db
Result {
  command: 'DROP',
  rowCount: null,
  oid: null,
  rows: [],
  fields: [],
  _parsers: [],
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false,
  _getTypeParser: [Function: bound ] }
client removed
```

I'm sure there's a simple answer to this, I feel bad for asking but I don't want to burn another hour banging my head against the wall.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem today. Since each function closes the pg pool, the subsequent calls couldn't perform their work. Made each one close the pool by default so they could continue to be called in isolation, but if a truthy value is passed in they will allow allow the pool to remain open so it can be used by other functions.

My new create tables example looks like this:

```
const createTables = async (isKeepingPoolOpen = false) => {

    const taskTableText = 
        `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
            acts(
                id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1 (),
                name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
                length INTERVAL NOT NULL,
                percent_complete INT NOT NULL,
                start_stamp TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (id)
            )
        `;

    return pool.query(taskTableText)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            isKeepingPoolOpen === true ? '' : pool.end();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            isKeepingPoolOpen === true ? '' : pool.end();
        });
}
```

My new 'call them all' function now looks like this:

```
const makeFresh = function() {
    const isKeepingPoolOpen = true;
    dropTables(isKeepingPoolOpen)
    .then(() => createTables(isKeepingPoolOpen))
    .then(() => seedTables(isKeepingPoolOpen))
    .then(() => {
        pool.end();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error: " + error);
        pool.end();
    });
}
```

Comment: Also using promises in a way that makes them wait their turn. I'm green with this async stuff, so if I'm using it wrong or unnecessarily please let me know.